# Syntax highlighting off when using scenario outline variables in conditions (1.4.1RC3)

Tags: karate

Here is a sample scenario that shows the syntax highlighting is not working correctly, however the code is not affected by this, just the visual aspect.
(test is just to show highlighting, not an actual test in use)

```
Feature:

  Scenario Outline:
    * def x = 1

    * def output = x != null ? (100 + <add>) : null
            * print 'output for add is ', output
    * def output = x != null ? (100 - <subtract>) : null
            * print 'output for subtract is ', output
    * def output = x != null ? (100 * <times>) : null
            * print 'output for times is ', output
    * def output = x != null ? (100 / <divide>) : null
            * print 'output for divide is ', output
    
    * def output = <add> != null ? (100 + <add>) : null
            * print 'output for add is ', output
    * def output = <subtract> != null ? (100 - <subtract>) : null
            * print 'output for subtract is ', output
    * def output = <times> != null ? (100 * <times>) : null
            * print 'output for times is ', output
    * def output = <divide> != null ? (100 / <divide>) : null
            * print 'output for divide is ', output

    Examples:
            | add | subtract | times | divide |
            | 1   | 2        | 3     | null   |
            | 2   | 3        | null  | 4      |
```

Here is what the syntax highlighting looks like in vsCode.
In the first screenshot, You can see that after the * in the first times, all the following lines are off in syntax.
[image]

In the second screenshot, with the above row commented out, you can see that the syntax after the initial  is off
[image]

In this last example I also tried to use the outline variables in a condition and ran into the same syntax problem after the first use
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `< >` placeholder notation is no longer recommended in Karate, and `Examples` columns are directly available as proper JS variables. If you have non-string types, you mark the column heading by appending a `!`.

Here is the revised code that works fine, also refer documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements

```
Feature:

Scenario Outline:
* def x = 1

* def output = x != null ? (100 + add) : null
      * print 'output for add is ', output
* def output = x != null ? (100 - subtract) : null
      * print 'output for subtract is ', output
* def output = x != null ? (100 * times) : null
      * print 'output for times is ', output
* def output = x != null ? (100 / divide) : null
      * print 'output for divide is ', output

* def output = add != null ? (100 + add) : null
      * print 'output for add is ', output
* def output = subtract != null ? (100 - subtract) : null
      * print 'output for subtract is ', output
* def output = times != null ? (100 * times) : null
      * print 'output for times is ', output
* def output = divide != null ? (100 / divide) : null
      * print 'output for divide is ', output

Examples:
      | add! | subtract! | times! | divide! |
      | 1    | 2         | 3      | null    |
      | 2    | 3         | null   | 4       |
```

Comment: The section you referenced still says the use can be with <>, in the last line before the examples: `These are best explained with examples. You can choose between the string-placeholder style <foo> or directly refer to the variable foo (or even the whole row JSON as __row) in JSON-friendly expressions.`.  The first example also references <> nomenclature for the variable use.

Comment: I think the #() nomenclature provides clarity on which are variables, and that appears to work within the syntax highlighting.  Thank you for pointing out this section with the different options.

Comment: However, when referencing a value as a part of a json object, ` * def device = equipmentAndServicesList.<newDevice>`, <> is the only method that works. #() results in `org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:25 Expected ident but found error
equipmentAndServicesList.#(newDevice)` with the carat at the #.  Same with 'Expected an operand but found error
`#(isCoam) != null ? karate.merge( deviceToActivate, { isCoam: #(isCoam) } ) : deviceToActivate`

Comment: I guess using a variable without special nomenclature is the only way, but that causes issues when trying to use the variable in a jsonpath `* def device = equipmentAndServicesList.newDevice` with newDevice coming from the outline examples.  Could you possibly clarify how this should be done, or if certain variable nomenclatures are required in certain situations?  BTW:  <> works when including the variable in the json path